# Nuget package delivers an old version of my DLL

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I wrote a NuGet package that when my other projects use it they get an old version of one of my DLLs.
I include the newest version of my DLL as a reference in my NuGet project.

Project1.nuspec:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
   <metadata>
       <id>CommonLibrary</id>
       <version>0.0.1</version>
       <authors>It's Me</authors>
       <owners>My Company/owners>
       <description>Shared Library for Common Code and Wrapper</description>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency id="NLog" version="4.5.7" />
       </dependencies>  
   </metadata>
   <files>
     <file src="CommonLibrary.dll" target="lib\net471" />
     <file src="HelperCode.dll" target="lib\net471" />
    </files>
 </package>
```

The CommonLibrary.dll (the project) my NuGet package delivers the correct latest DLL, but that HelperCode.dll is always an older version.

in my project, I created a directory named: "binaries" and in that directory is the latest version of HelperCode.DLL.  I reference that latest version in my project.  So the NuGet package should deliver the latest version. I gave it a property of "Copy Local Always"

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?